# Undefined variable from import jinja2

Tags: python, eclipse, jinja2

Am working with `jinja2` templates (well, trying to) but i get the error message

```
"undefined variable from import jinja2"
```

triggered by the marked part of these pieces of code:

```
def jinja2_factory(self, app):

    j = jinja2.Jinja2(app) # here("Jinja2")
    j.enviroment.globals.update({
            'uri_for': webapp2.uri_for,
    })
    return j

@webapp2.cached_property
def jinja2(self):
    return jinja2.get_jinja2(factory=jinja2_factory, app=self.app) # here ("get_jinja2")

def render_response(self, _template, **context):
    ctx = {'user': self.user_model}
    ctx.update(context)
    rv = self.jinja2.render_template(_template, **ctx)
    self.response.write(rv)
```

I have followed the steps required to use `jinja2` in my python code.
This includes adding

```
libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

to my `app.yaml` file and then adding `import jinja2` to the top of my python script., but the problem still persists.I even went as far as downloading jinja2 and adding the source folder containing `__init__.py` to `external libraries` in `PyDev PythonPath` but no luck. Am i missing something else?

Comment: That's the way it is in the tutorial am following.Besides, i tried to remove that and nothing changes.

Comment: I never use Eclipse myself; it was a guess, unfortunately wrong.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i finally solved the problem.But i don't really know much about the `self` keyword other than it refers to current object(?) Do you think it was a good idea adding it to my code in this context?

Comment: But `jinja2` refers to the *module* here (a global), not the `cached_property`-decorated method! Your change may fix the dumb Eclipse code linter, but it introduced an error in your implementation.

Comment: I thought so too.I'll just delete the answer and finish with the app to see what comes up.Thanks.